# BFBC2 Crashes on random screens

Tags: pc, battlefield-bad-company-2, technical-issues

So far, I haven't been able to play BFBC2 yet. Sometimes, it crashes(and throws me back to the desktop) at the very first loading screen before the main menu. If it doesn't crash there, it will crash(and throw me back to the desktop) on the multiplayer loading screen, or it will freeze at the single player screen that says "In the year blahblah, sea of japan, etc."

What's wrong/how might i fix it?

Comment: Is this the Steam version? Can you run any other 3D games?

Comment: Yup, it's steam, and I can definately play 3d games, most recently, fallen earth and minecraft :D

Comment: Hmmmmm, I was having a problem with crysis not being able to move or look around, and a friend suggested that I reinstall it. I'll try reinstalling bfbc2, and go eat lunch, and then see how that works.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give us anymore information machinespecs dxdiag?

to do a dxdiag 
1. Start => Run => Type in "dxdiag"
2. Choose "Yes"
3. Click "Save All Information"
4. Copy and paste contents of dxdiag txt file to here.

then we can see if we can help you further.

Comment: DxDiag's too big for this comments section, here ya go: http://pastebin.com/iQSTSGFz

Answer (score 1):

Try running [DirectX web setup](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&displaylang=en) to check for and install missing components.

Answer (score 1):

Hey person who I don't know, maybe you should try reinstalling the game! :D

Comment: Hey helpful person that I also don't know, reinstalling the game fixed it, thanks!

Comment: hey, get a room, you two! :P